# Json String Date to date Object with AngularJS Http get

Tags: json, angularjs, date, datetime, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to order a list by date and popularity. From service i have a json response which has date in string format. Is it possible to change the date from Http get response to date object so that i want to use OrderBy filter to sort the list by date.

My json is

```
{
  "Name": "Paul ",
  "Country": "SINGAPORE",
  "Date": "12/31/14 20:40",
  "Rating": "2"
}
```

Comment: Yes that is possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting string to date in js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the date string to the [Date Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) 
Put this in your controller:

```
myApp.controller("MyPersonController", function($scope){
    for (var i in $scope.persons) {
        $scope.persons[i].Date = new Date($scope.persons[i].Date);
    }
});
```

If you have problems with formatting, I would recommend a date wrapper like [MomentJs](http://momentjs.com/)